# How to require all nodes to satisfy an XPath predicate for the predicate to return true

Tags: xpath

Given a structure as shown below, in which a `RootFolder` element can contain any number of `Folder` elements, including nested `Folder` elements, I want to select all `RootFolder` elements that contain at least one descendant `File` element for which all of its ancestor `Folder` elements (if any) have the `visible` attribute set to true.

```
<Root>
  <!-- This should be included -->
  <RootFolder>
    <Folder visible="true">
      <File />
    </Folder>
    <Folder visible="false">
      <File />
    </Folder>
  </RootFolder>
  <!-- This should be included -->
  <RootFolder>
    <Folder visible="true">
      <Folder visible="true">
        <File />
      </Folder>
    </Folder>
  </RootFolder>
  <!-- This should not be included -->
  <RootFolder>
    <Folder visible="false">
      <File />
    </Folder>
  </RootFolder>
  <!-- This should not be included -->
  <RootFolder>
    <Folder visible="false">
      <Folder visible="true">
        <File />
      </Folder>
    </Folder>
  </RootFolder>
  <!-- This should not be included -->
  <RootFolder>
    <Folder visible="true">
      <Folder visible="false">
        <File />
      </Folder>
    </Folder>
  </RootFolder>
</Root>
```

The following XPath expression does not do the trick because it includes the last two `RootFolder` elements.

```
//RootFolder[descendant::File[ancestor::Folder[@visible='true']]]
```

Given the following quote from the section on "Predicate Semantics" in http://courses.ischool.berkeley.edu/i290-14/s05/lecture-7/allslides.html, it is indeed expected that the XPath expression above works as it does. So, perhaps what I am trying to do is not possible, but I just wanted to make sure I am not missing something.

> Predicates result in an expression value that is converted to a
>   boolean... A node set is true if it is non-empty.

Is what I am trying to achieve possible using an XPath predicate or some equivalent XPath expression? Is the only alternative to programmatically confirm that all ancestors satisfy the condition?

Comment: Does the Folder have a nested folder? Or is a typo in your sample xml.

Comment: No, it is not a typo: the number of nested folders is indefinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were close in your initial attempt. I think you just need to check for a `File` that doesn't have an ancestor `Folder` that has a `visible` attribute set to `false`...

```xml
//RootFolder[.//File[not(ancestor::Folder/@visible='false')]]
```

Or this if you don't care what the value of `visible` is as long as it's not `true`...

```
//RootFolder[.//File[not(ancestor::Folder[not(@visible='true')])]]
```

Comment: Thanks! I believe the second expression is the best fit, to allow for the possibility that the `visible` attribute might be missing or set to some other value besides true or false.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below xpath.

```
 //RootFolder[.//File[not(ancestor::Folder[@visible='false'])]]
```

Here are checking if the Root Folder have any Folder with visible= false and also checking if the folder have the File.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, this doesn't quite answer the question for a couple of reasons: 1) The XPath expression doesn't achieve the desired result if a File element is a child of a Folder element nested in another Folder element (as shown in the OP XML); and 2) unless I am mistaken, the XPath expression does not show an example of requiring all nodes to satisfy a predicate for the predicate to return true.

Comment: Thanks again for the prompt response. This is definitely closer, but the first predicate doesn't allow for a case in which a File element is contained within ancestor Folder elements that are parallel/siblings to other Folder elements within a given RootFolder. I've updated the example XML in the OP to clarify the structure and possible scenarios. Using the expression you provided with the updated XML example, only the second RootFolder is returned.

Comment: How about this? `//RootFolder[count(.//Folder[@visible='true'][count(./File)>0])>0]`

Comment: Thanks again, but this doesn't account for the second to last case in the updated XML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196348/discussion-between-supputuri-and-gerry).

Comment: Try with that one last xpath. Updated the answer and the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 2.0 you can use

```
//RootFolder[every $a in ancestor::* satisfies $a/@visible='true']
```

which is probably the clearest way of saying it.

If you've only got XPath 1.0, you can express it as a double negative:

```
//RootFolder[not(ancestor::*[not(@visible='true')])]
```

i.e. find every `RootFolder` that doesn't have an ancestor that doesn't have `@visible='true'`.

By the way, it helps to say which XPath version you are using, since the answers for any complex query will be different depending on the version.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't think either query is quite right because the predicate is being applied to the `RootFolder` element rather than its descendant `File` elements. Also, I think specifying `Folder` instead of `*` would be more correct based on the filter I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to illustrate the coding technique, not to write the code for you.